# Написанная программа ищет лучшую формулу для предугадывания числа где 0 один результат, 1 другой . Насколько верно сравнивать её с нейросетью?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Насколько программа верная и как её можно улучшить?

```
import random
import itertools
example = [[1.4,2.74,2.35,1.05],[2.42,1.5,0.7,1.5],[1.63,2.14,1.28,0.39],[1.37,2.87,0.92,0.62],[1.85,1.85,1.18,0.98],[2.09,1.66,0.95,0.42],[1.66,2.09,1.21,1.375],[2.0,1.72,0.57,1.02],[1.42,2.67,1.05,1.46],[2.11,1.65,0.61,0.79],[1.87,1.83,1.21,0.68],[1.38,2.81,1.02,0.42],[2.93,1.35,1.22,0.54],[1.85,1.85,1.41,1.14],[1.81,1.81,1.18,1.025],[1.88,1.83,0.73,0.66],[2.0,1.72,0.73,0.82],[1.44,2.61,0.97,1.73],[1.42,2.66,1.35,1.36],[1.41,2.71,1.85,0.82],[1.86,1.84,1.46,0.825],[1.85,1.85,1.03,1.35],]
answer = [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,]
list_0 = []
list_1 = []
list_0_copy = []
list_1_copy = []
index = [0, 1, 2, 3]
index_every = []
sign = [0, 1, 2, 3]
a = 0
b = []
c = []
x = []
w1 = 0
w2 = 0
w3 = 0
s1 = 0
s2 = 0
s3 = 0
evaluation_0 = []
evaluation_1 = []
evaluation_0_middle = []
evaluation_1_middle = []
fault_0 = []
fault_1 = []
fault_union = 0
best_evaluation = [0]
fault_every = 0
for i in range(len(answer)):    #Распределения в списки 0 и 1
    every = answer[a]
    if every == 0:
        list_0.append( example[a] )
    elif every == 1:
        list_1.append( example[a] )
    a += 1
index_every = list( itertools.permutations(index)) #Все возможные перестоновки 4 входных чисел
sign_stage = list( itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sign,3)) #Считает и заносит в список все варианты знаков
print((sign_stage))
for i in index_every:
    for j in list_0:
        x = [j[k] for k in i]
        list_0_copy.append( x )   #Одно из расположений 0 по индексу из index_every
    for l in list_1:
        x = [l[k] for k in i]   #Одно из расположений 1 по индексу из index_every
        list_1_copy.append( x )
    for q in sign_stage:        #Перебирает все возможные знаки
        n1 = q[0]
        n2 = q[1]
        n3 = q[2]
        for w in list_0_copy:   # 0_+    1_-    2_*    3_/
            if n1 == 0:     #n1
                w1 = w[0] + w[1]
            elif n1 == 1:
                w1 = w[0] - w[1]
            elif n1 == 2:
                w1 = w[0] * w[1]
            elif n1 == 3:
                w1 = w[0] / w[1]
            if n2 == 0:     #n2
                w2 = w1 + w[2]
            elif n2 == 1:
                w2 = w1 - w[2]
            elif n2 == 2:
                w2 = w1 * w[2]
            elif n2 == 3:
                w2 = w1 / w[2]
            if n3 == 0:     #3
                w3 = w2 + w[3]
            elif n3 == 1:
                w3 = w2 - w[3]
            elif n3 == 2:
                w3 = w2 * w[3]
            elif n3 == 3:
                w3 = w2 / w[3]
            evaluation_0.append( w3 )
        for s in list_1_copy:   # 0_+    1_-    2_*    3_/
            if n1 == 0:     #n1
                s1 = s[0] + s[1]
            elif n1 == 1:
                s1 = s[0] - s[1]
            elif n1 == 2:
                s1 = s[0] * s[1]
            elif n1 == 3:
                s1 = s[0] / s[1]
            if n2 == 0:     #n2
                s2 = s1 + s[2]
            elif n2 == 1:
                s2 = s1 - s[2]
            elif n2 == 2:
                s2 = s1 * s[2]
            elif n2 == 3:
                s2 = s1 / s[2]
            if n3 == 0:     #3
                s3 = s2 + s[3]
            elif n3 == 1:
                s3 = s2 - s[3]
            elif n3 == 2:
                s3 = s2 * s[3]
            elif n3 == 3:
                s3 = s2 / s[3]
            evaluation_1.append( s3 )
        evaluation_0_middle = sum( evaluation_0 ) / len( evaluation_0 )     #Среднее значение получаймых чисел для 0
        evaluation_1_middle = sum( evaluation_1 ) / len( evaluation_1 )     #Среднее значение получаймых чисел для 1
        if evaluation_0_middle > evaluation_1_middle:       # 0 > 1
            for t in evaluation_0:      #Погрешность для 0
                if t < evaluation_0_middle:
                    fault_0.append( evaluation_0_middle - t )
            for p in evaluation_1:      #Погрешность для 1
                if p > evaluation_1_middle:
                    fault_1.append( p - evaluation_1_middle )
        elif evaluation_0_middle < evaluation_1_middle:     # 0 < 1
            for m in evaluation_0:      #Погрешность для 0
                if m > evaluation_0_middle:
                    fault_0.append( m - evaluation_0_middle )
            for f in evaluation_1:      #Погрешность для 1
                if f < evaluation_1_middle:
                    fault_1.append( evaluation_1_middle - f )
        evaluation_0 = []
        evaluation_1 = []
        fault_0 = sum( fault_0) / len(fault_0)  #считает среднию погрешность
        fault_1 = sum( fault_1) / len(fault_1)
        fault_union = fault_0 + fault_1
        fault_every = fault_union
        fault_union = abs( evaluation_0_middle - evaluation_1_middle ) / fault_union    #среднем значение / Погрешность
        print(fault_union)
        if fault_union > best_evaluation[0]:        #Наименьшая погрешность и заносятся данные для расчета
            del best_evaluation[:]
            best_evaluation.append(fault_union)
            best_evaluation.append(i)
            best_evaluation.append(n1)
            best_evaluation.append(n2)
            best_evaluation.append(n3)
            best_evaluation.append(evaluation_0_middle)
            best_evaluation.append(evaluation_1_middle)
            best_evaluation.append(fault_every)
print(best_evaluation)
```

Comment: Наверняка код можно сократить хотя бы в длину. Присваивания можно делать в одну строчку `a, b, c = 0, 0, 0` и повторяющиеся операции лучше делать через цикл по списку.

Comment: Судя по всему, вы перебираете все возможные формулы для поиска оптимальной. Это значительно отличается от нейросети, которая при обучении перебирает только некоторые варианты. По сути двухслойная нейросеть, содержащая по 10 нейронов на каждом слое, представляет собой десятипараметрическую формулу, содержащую 100 операций. Если вы попробуете перебрать все подобные формулы, то вам не удастся даже немного продвинуться до самой смерти Солнца.

Comment: То есть в формулу надо добавлять дополнительные цифры ,что бы максимально разграничить 1 и 0?

Comment: нейросеть подразумевает нейроны и связи. у васже чтото другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать, называется системой линейных уравнений. На питоне это несколько строк. Решение я приводила здесь: [Предсказываение последовательности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279459/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8/1280143#1280143)

Вариант я потом корректировала, но ответ ищите в первой части.

Ваш код у меня, к сожалению, не компилируется. Привожу вывод для ваших данных, который получился у меня (сначала уравнение, потом ответы - рядом правильное значение). Это при всего лишь 4х параметрах оптимальный вариант:

```
[ 0.29877656 -0.42943355 0.51303086 0.33108377]
0.7948997407196119 1
0.9346362036880386 1
0.3538201709639155 0
-0.14589006957844308 0
0.6881230784935755 1
0.5380178202863463 0
0.6744604935451852 0
0.4890604483953289 0
0.29973984301122025 1
0.4963581868982721 0
0.6187530769786539 1
-0.13204995786553886 0
1.1003629154131027 1
0.8590935792622079 1
0.7082481274721618 1
0.36886435335212764 1
0.5049286333312047 1
0.3798315347432345 0
0.42483506067994914 0
0.47810581561472554 0
0.7877358374299694 1
0.7336694422636876 1

[Program finished]
```

Понятно, что это не НС, т.к. здесь линейное уравнение и некоторые ответы не совпадают, а нейронные сети достаточно не линейны из-за слоистости и слаболинейных функций активации.
Мой вывод по вашей задаче - это один нейрон без сдвига (это был бы 5й параметр) и активирующей функции.
Задача поставлена правильно, но ваш метод - это перебор, поэтому сравнивать его с НС не правильно.