# Предсказываение последовательности

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Задача состоит в следующем: есть набор данных следующего вида `[(1,1),(2,4),(3,6),...]`
Нужно попытаться предсказать например для числа 4 предсказать её значение.

То есть пара `(1,1)` представляет пару x, y. Нужно на основе имеющихся наборах координат построить модель и предсказывать значение от подаваемое значения.

Пока в этой теме новичок. Если есть ссылки что почитать или какие-либо примеры, буду признателен.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно решить линейную систему уравнений методом наименьших квадратов (МНК)?
У Вас есть матрица А - она может быть не квадратной, то есть Ваши значения [(1,1),(2,4),(3,6),...] - матрица А, матрица b - некие ответы типа [4,...]. Для решения этой системы нужно найти произведение A транспонированная на A.
Получится матрица Z. Затем, надо найти обратную матрице Z.
Решениями (x) будет являться Z', умноженная на A транспонированную, умноженные на b. В Вашем случае получится 2 числа.
Попробуйте сначала так, а потом какую-то более сложную аппроксимацию.
Вам поможет лекция: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3JzojqLteo

Вот код:

```
import numpy as np

W=np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0]) # массив весов
A=np.array([[1,1],[2,4],[3,6]])#левая часть системы
b=np.array([1,2,3])#правая часть системы
A1=A.T
Z=np.dot(A1,A)
Z=np.linalg.inv(Z)
W1=np.dot(Z,A1)
W=np.dot(W1,b)
#проверка - результатом должно быть 3
print(np.dot(W,[3,6]))

# что дают числа 5 и 7 - у меня 5
print(np.dot(W,[5,7]))
```

Исправляю ответ: Вам нужна обыкновенная экстраполяция, если Вы знаете x в 4й паре чисел.

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import scipy

x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,4,6]
extrapolator = UnivariateSpline(x, y,k=2)
print(extrapolator(2))# 4
print(extrapolator(4))# 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Даю ответ как для новичка.

Регрессия решает вашу задачу.

Открываете любую книгу по  статистике, машинному обучению, эконометрике.... открываете раздел по регрессии и изучаете. Правда, возможно, для понимания придется проштудировать и предыдущие разделы, но это уже зависит от вашей предварительной подготовки.

Советовать что-либо бессмысленно, ибо источников даже не море, а океан, на любой вкус, цвет, уровень образования. Просто набиваете слово "регрессия" в Гуугл и выбираете что больше по вкусу (и по зубам).

Потом, как появятся конкретные вопросы - возвращаетесь сюда и задаете.